# How to solve error of can't create a test file and keyring migration in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
mysqld: Can not perform keyring migration : Invalid --keyring-migration-source option.
2023-08-21T02:32:14.652983Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.34) starting as process 9340
2023-08-21T02:32:14.704670Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2023-08-21T02:32:14.704927Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2023-08-21T02:32:14.707534Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011084] [Server] Keyring migration failed.
2023-08-21T02:32:14.709023Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-08-21T02:32:14.709383Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.34)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Trying to create a new user to use mysql in vscode but it's giving error can't create a test file